# SQL datetime format - timezone or offset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a query used in SSIS that returns the date in this format:

```
2016-10-30 19:32:24.7960000 -08:00
```

When it gets inserted in the staging table it inserts:

```
2016-10-31 03:32:24.797
```

I assume is has something to do with the  -08:00 at the end but I have never seen this before and can't find documentation explaining what it is or how it works?

All these transactions happen in one timezone - so if this is some kind of timezone tracking I want to ignore it.  Both the source and destination databases are SQL Server 2014 and SSIS is VisualStudio 2013

Comment: The -08:00 refers to a negative 8 hours offset from UTC time.

Comment: how do I ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

It must be SSIS that decides how to handle the datetimeoffset conversion.  If I cast as datetime is the source query it truncates the UTC offset

```
select cast (end_date as datetime)
```

But if I let SSIS do it through a Source > Destination dataflow it applies the offset before converting to datetime and inserts the UTC time.